# How to access elements of a matrix array via pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I can't seem to find any info on how to access elements of an array via pointer in a function, I tried following multiple answers but none of them seem to work for me.

My task is next: Write a program in C with `m x n` dimension with elements being randomly generated from 0 to 9. Using two new functions calculate the sum of even elements and count the number of elements being equal to zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SumEven(int *a, int n, int m, int *sum){

}

void EqualToZero(int *a, int n, int m, int *number){

}

int main()
{
    int** a;
    int m, n, l, i, j, r, sum;

    printf("Enter number of columns for matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter number of rows for matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = (int **) malloc(m*sizeof(int));

    for (l = 0 ; l < m ; l++){
        a[l] = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    printf("\n");
    printf("Your matrix is:\n");
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
            r = rand() % 10;
            a[i][j] = r;
            printf("%d ", r);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    SumEven(&a, n, m);

    return(0);
}
```

As you can see in the provided code I left those functions empty as I don't know how to pass the matrix to them and access their elements so I can be able to print my results.

Also my pseudo code for the logic for the functions themselves are:

```
if(a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
     printf("%d ", a[i][j])
```

and

```
 if(a[i][j] == 0)
     printf("%d ", a[i][j])
```

Also those parameters of the function are predefined in my task, so I have to follow them.

EDIT: I also don't know if I'm even passing the same matrix to the function with `SumEven(&a, n, m);`. I tried outputing the address of the matrix and using `printf("%d", &a)` to display an address both from `main()` and `SumEven()` functions.

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! 2) "matrix is commonly synomously to 2D array. You don't have a construct in your code like that. And none which can be used as one. 3) Use a 2D array; that is straight-ahead syntactically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This code may help. It does the following:

1. For an arbitrary array of integers, sum the elements of the array 
   - using a pointer to the SUM function

2. For an arbitrary array of integers, count the number of zero elements in
   the array - using a pointer to the COUNTZERO function


    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // sum the elements of the matrix
    void sum(int* arr, int rows, int cols, int* result)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sum = sum + arr[i*cols + j];
            }
        }

        *result = sum;
    }

    // count the number of zero elements in the matrix
    void countZero(int* arr, int rows, int cols, int* result)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                if (arr[i*cols + j] ==0) count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        *result = count;
    }


    // arbitrary initialisation of 2D array of ints (force last entry of the array to equal zero - for testing purposes)
    void init2D(int *arr, int rows, int cols) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                arr[i*cols + j] = 1;
            }
        }

        // use this to test the countZero function
        arr[(rows-1)*(cols-1)] = 0;

    }

    int main() {

        int *array;     // will hold a 2D array of integers
        int N = 10;     // arbitrary number of rows     
        int M = 5;      // arbitrary num cols

        // 2D array of integers expressed as one "contiguous row" of memory 
        // make sure your indexing is correct when referenceing the array for  (i,j)th element
        array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
        if (array != NULL) {
            init2D(array, N, M);
        }

        // the function pointer
        void(*general)(int*,int,int,int*);   

        // will contain the sum result
        int sumAll = 0;
        int* ptsumAll = &sumAll;

        // make the function pointer point to the sum function
        general = &sum;

        // sum the contents of the array
        general(array,N,M, ptsumAll);
        printf("sum of array elements: %d\n", *ptsumAll);

        // contains a count of the zero elements in the array
        int count =0;
        int* ptcount = &count;

        // make the function pointer point to the count function
        general = &countZero;

        // count the number of zero element in the array
        general(array, N, M,ptcount);
        printf("number of zeros: %d\n", *ptcount);

        free(array);

        return 0;
    }
```

some references:
https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. It's working now thanks to @Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

These will be your function prototypes:

```
void SumEven(int **a, int n, int m,int *sum);
void EqualToZero(int **a, int n, int m,int *number);
```

since you are passing `a`(double pointer) from calling then the there should be a double pointer(`int **a`) to receive it.

Calling:

```
SumEven(a, n, m,&sum);
EqualToZero(a, n, m,&number);
```

And this is how you can access the array inside your function:

```
void SumEven(int **a, int n, int m,int *sum){
    int i,j,tsum=0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
            if(a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                tsum+=a[i][j];
                printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    *sum=tsum;
}
```

Also there is an error in this line `a[l] = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int));` (‘`int**`’ to ‘`int*`’assignment),it should be  `a[l] = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));`.

Comment: This works, however adresses of matrix `a` isn't the same when I call the function to print the addres from `main()` and `SumEven`. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Adresses would be same(they should be) in both functions,I checked them!.

Comment: Just did few changes and it works flawlessly now, thanks a lot for your help, just one more question. What's the difference between `int **a` and `int *a[]`? Once again thanks a lot, I've been cracking my head for the last couple of hours about this.

Comment: both are same thing ! I added the reason why it is necessary in the parameter,you cannot receive &a(address of a double pointer or ***a) by *a(pointer) (types should match)

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to help you with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SumEven(int *a, int n, int m, int *sum){
    //put this statement in 2 nested for loops of size n and m
     if(a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
        sum += a[i][j];
}

void EqualToZero(int *a, int n, int m, int *number){
    //put this statement in 2 nested for loops of size n and m
      if(a[i][j] == 0)
           number++;
}

int main()
{
int** a;
int m, n, l, i, j, r, sum;

printf("Enter number of columns for matrix: ");
scanf("%d", &m);

printf("Enter number of rows for matrix: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

a = (int **) malloc(m*sizeof(int));
//should be m*sizeof(int*)

for (l = 0 ; l < m ; l++){
    a[l] = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    //should be cast as (int*)
} 

//I suggest you take look at declaring 2d arrays in C 
time_t t;

srand((unsigned)time(&t));

printf("\n");
printf("Your matrix is:\n");
printf("\n");

for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
    for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
        r = rand() % 10;
        a[i][j] = r;
        printf("%d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n");

SumEven(&a, n, m);
//need to pass &sum to this function. Also make sure it is initialized to 0
//call EqualToZero() function with proper parameters.
return(0);
//return 0; not return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I changed all you wrote but still get an error `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` inside the function when I follow your steps.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(( *(*(a + i) + j) % 2 ) == 0 )
     printf("%d", *(*(a + i) + j) )


if( *(*(a + i) + j) == 0 )
     printf("%d", *(*(a + i) + j) )
```

This is how you do it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example, given a 3D array

```
int buffer[5][7][6];
```

An element at location `[2][1][2]` can be accessed as `buffer[2][1][2]` or `*( *( *(buffer + 2) + 1) + 2)`.

[Reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-pointer-arithmetic-in-cc/)